# Finding Bernoulli's Equation for a Gas Flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics

> For inviscid, compressible, but **isentropic** ($s=$ constant) flow of a diatomic gas, the relationship between the pressure and density is
>   $$p = A(s)\rho^{\gamma}\quad\text{where}\quad \gamma = \frac{c_p}{c_v} = \frac{7}{5}$$
>   Give Bernoulli's equation for such a gas flow. Explain why the pressure term
>   is more important here than in a constant-density liquid flow.

Trying to search through the online notes there is section called Bernoulli's Equation which says:
$$\frac{\partial\underline{u}}{\partial t} - \underline{u}\times\underline{\omega} = -\underline{\nabla}\mathcal{H}\quad\text{where}\quad \mathcal{H}(\underline{r},t) = \underline{\nabla}\bigg[\int\frac{1}{\rho}\mathrm{d}p + \frac{1}{2}||\underline{u}||^2 +\chi\bigg]$$
is the *Bernoulli function*, where assuming $p = p(\rho)$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\rho}\underline{\nabla}p = \underline{\nabla}\bigg[\int\frac{1}{\rho}\mathrm{d}p\bigg]$$
Do I just rearrange so that:
$$\rho = \exp\Bigg({\frac{5\ln\bigg(\frac{p}{A(s)}\bigg)}{7}}\Bigg) = \bigg(\frac{p}{A(s)}\bigg)^{5/7}$$
And then try to just sub in $\rho$ into the LHS or RHS?

Comment: You need to find either $$ \underline{\nabla}\bigg[\int\frac{1}{\rho}\mathrm{d}p\bigg]$$ or $$ \frac{1}{\rho}\underline{\nabla}p $$ in order to substitute it in the Bernoulli's equation. I suggest you take the gradient of pressure per viscosity (the second one) and substitute it in Bernoulli's equation. Note that this is pressure head. You also need to find velocity head and height head to fully determine the Bernoulli's equation.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\rho}\underline{\nabla}p = \dfrac{\underline{\nabla} (A(s)\rho^{\gamma})}{\rho}=?$

Comment: I can't find anywhere how to find $\underline{\nabla} \rho$? It isn't a vector so I don't understand how to do it... @MehrdadZandigohar

Comment: It depends on the gas flow direction. For instance, if the flow is in a pipe, then it only has one direction and the gradient will convert to a derivative. Let's say $\underline{\nabla} \rho$ will be $\dfrac{d\rho}{dx}$ if the flow is in $x$ direction (i.e. density only changes with respect to $x$)

Comment: But, from what I am given in the question, how is it possible to know? @MehrdadZandigohar

Comment: Then consider the general form. Your fluid is compressible and as a result of that it is expected for $\rho$ to be: $\rho=\rho(x,y,z)$ so the gradient will be like: $\nabla \rho=\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}i + \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial y}j + \dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}k $